# wrong currency on contribution pages - how to correct?

Tags: civicontribute, currency

I have set default currency to GBP, created memberships with GBP amounts, and set GBP as the currency within my contribution page.

But membership fee displays in USD on the contribution page and when sending payees to paypal (my only payment processor) attempts to charge of a USD amount.

What am I doing wrong please?

thank you:)

Comment: I can't replicate your issue on 5.4.0. Can you re-check if the membership page settings are correct? And also can you provide the CiviCRM version you trying on?

Comment: thanks for the reply Pradeep.  I'm not sure what you mean by membership page settings?  I have Currency on the 'Amounts' tab of the Contribution Page set to GBP.  I think perhaps it is because when I set up the Contribution Page the default currency was $ and I have now corrected to GBP and the contribution page has not picked up the change.  Will create a new contribution page and see if this does the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Try re-saving the contribution pages so that the new default currency is updated. You can cross check the currency used for contribution page using api explorer, it might be helpful to track the error.

HTH

Pradeep